# Inline assembly to bytecodes during preprocessing/compilation?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, gcc, compilation

I have a program which I would like to patch during runtime that is composed of many long functions. I figured it would be easier if I could patch specific ranges of instructions inside the functions instead of just completely rewriting them.

To do this, I'd like to create a function which, given the inline assembly, start address, and end address of a process, will replace all the assembly code in the address range with the custom given assembly.

If there is memory left in the address range after writing all the assembly's bytes using `WriteProcessMemory` (that is, if the buffer for the bytes is smaller than the address range) the remaining address space is filled with `nop` instructions. If there is not enough space to fit the assembly, the entire address range is filled with `nop` instructions and a `jmp` instruction is placed at the start which will redirect the routine to a function containing all of the assembly.

For this to work I would need to know the bytecodes of the assembly during compilation time, which I am unsure on how to do, or if it is even possible. What's more, I would prefer that the function would be a macro which would behave a lot like the inline assembly used by GCC, so the function would look like:

```
BYTE* asm_bytecode = get_asm_bytecodes ( 0x0<start_address>, 0x0<end_address>, 
    "mov eax, eax;"
);
WriteProcessMemory(..., asm_bytecode, ...);
```

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to get inline assembly bytecodes during compilation? If so, how?
- Is it possible to leverage the inline assembly format in a custom macro like in my example?
- Is there a better way of verbosely patching a program than the one I suggested?

Note that I am using MinGW for the GCC on Windows.

Comment: You cannot get the bytecode you want at compile time because the assembly generation is the last step of the compilation. All variables and macros no longer exist during this last step (GCC use gas to do that). Alternatively, you can play with labels and function pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `asm` outside a function to assemble any sequence of instructions you like, and create labels to mark the start and end.  Then you'll have these bytes in memory, and can copy them where you like.

```
asm(".text \n\t"
    ".global my_code \n"
    "my_code: \n\t"
    "frob %rax \n\t"
    "grind $12345, %rbx \n\t"
    // ...
    ".global end_of_my_code \n"
    "end_of_my_code: \n\t"
);

extern unsigned char *my_code;
extern unsigned char *end_of_my_code;
size_t my_code_size = end_of_my_code - my_code;

void overwrite(...) {
    WriteProcessMemory(..., my_code, my_code_size, ...);
}
```

(I forget whether MinGW needs leading underscores on symbols.  Add if necessary.)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to know.